# how to write inside a circle inside a circle in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to write text inside a circular shape in uwp or xaml
below are the syntax

```
  <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,-266,10,10" Fill="#F2794B" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
```

image given below[image]

Comment: Add *TextBlock* in your XAML - normally they are resolved in order they are in the code (without modifying ZIndex), therefore your textbox will appear on circle. You will just have to position both things correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Instead create a `Grid` the same size as the `Ellipse` and put the `Ellipse` and a `TextBlock` into it.